# How to archive or delete Redis log file

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis, servicestack.redis

I am using Redis open source from redis.io. I have configured my redis.conf file and set the **loglevel** as "**warning**" from default setting "**notice**". This helps in reducing the logfile size. My log file is growing in size and I did not find any documentation on redis.io regarding the log file archival or planned deletion using any command or using any maintenance tool.

I have also tried **Redis on windows** (https://github.com/ServiceStack/redis-windows), from MS open tech, there is also same issue i.e. no log archival or deletion command is available .

So does anyone have experienced how to archive or delete and manage the Redis logs on the production?